# Printing value as Country name not working Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i have an app where im using a custom country list, its working for some classes but for others not..

For example..

For this class :

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :division, :from, :to, :country_id

  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :country

  DIVISION = %w{
    first_division
    second_division
    third_division
    amateur_division
  }

  YEARS = (1950..(Time.now.strftime('%Y')).to_i).to_a

end
```

Its working ok when i use in the view

```
 <% @player.clubs.each do |club| %>
      <% if club.name.present? %>
        <p>
          <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.name' %> :
          <%= club.name %><br />
          <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.country' %> :
          <%= club.country.name %><br />
          <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.division' %> :
          <%= t "generales.#{club.division}" if club.division.present? %><br />
          <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.from' %>
          <%= club.from %>
          <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.to' %>
          <%= club.to %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But for this simple class

```
class Citizen < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :country_id

  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :country
end
```

I have this on view

```
 <% @player.citizens.each do |citizen| %>

          <%= t('generales.citizen') %> :
          <%= citizen.country.name %>

    <% end %>
```

This causes undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

If i change to

```
 <% @player.citizens.each do |citizen| %>

          <%= t('generales.citizen') %> :
          <%= citizen %>

    <% end %>
```

Then i Got

```
#<Citizen:0x007f8511dd8978>
```

If i try this

```
<%= citizen.country_id %>
```

I echo the Country_id stored , how can i echo this id as the country name? thanks

Can anybody tellme what am i doing wrong?

Here is the Country.rb Model

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iso, :name, :printable_name, :iso3, :numcode
end
```

Comment: it means that there no `country` associated with the `citizen`. How are you saving the country for a citizen?

Comment: Are all your `citizen.country_id` values valid? An FK inside the database would be helpful here.

Comment: yes citizen.country_id is printing the country_id where can i check the country definition for clubs, to do the same

Comment: Please post your country model and table attributes

Comment: Sorry for delay im back, i just edited the question with country model, table is just (id, player_id, country_id) they are saving info ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get the country name as per your `citizen` model citizen belongs to `country` and country model country should have a `name` so displaying country name as you want just use `<%=citizen.country.name%>` look below

```
   <% @player.citizens.each do |citizen| %>

      <%= t('generales.citizen') %> :
      <%= t(citizen.country.name) unless citizen.nil? && citizen.country.nil? %>

   <% end %>
```

Comment: That was my first choice , as is described i get this error undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Ok thanks the problem know its printing in uppercase, im using i18n so countries are on config>locals>en.yml etc fr.yml so on.. But yes im printig the values now.. i know realize the second option is null cause you have multiple..

Comment: sorry i am not getting

Comment: I get the country name in database, but i do not get the country name in my lenguaje files for i18n =(.. In the form when i ask, i use Country.all.collect {|p| [ t("generales."+p.iso), p.id ] },

Comment: ok....check my updated post...if your country all name are defined/mapped in fr.yml then it will work

Comment: thanks i get the same value for example MEXICO insted of México, wich is the value in lenguaje file in a prev comment i show the t() i use in form where country names are ok

Comment: because you did not mapped it in you fr.yml ....ok do one thing go to application.rb and write `config.i18n.default_locale = :"fr"`..look more info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html